# Python File errors

Tags: python

```
File = input("Please enter the name for your txt. file: ")

fileName = (File + ".txt")
WRITE = "w"
APPEND = "a"

file = []
name = " "
while name != "DONE" :
    name = input("Please enter the guest name (Enter DONE if there is no   more names) : ").upper()
   fileName.append(name)
fileName.remove("DONE")
print("The guests list in alphabetical order, and it will save in " + fileName + " :")
file.sort()
for U in file :
    print(U)
file = open(fileName, mode = WRITE)
file.write(name)
file.close()
print("file written successfully.")
```

I am just practicing to write the file in Python, but something bad happened.

[image: The code.]
[image: The error description.]

Here are still some errors about this:

```
fileName.remove("DONE")
```

Still showing 'str' error.

Answer (score 1):

Python strings are immutable. Therefore you can't use `append()` on them. Use `+=` instead:

```
fileName += name
```

which is shorthand for

```
fileName = fileName + name
```

Note how nothing is appended to the string, instead a new one is created and then assigned to `fileName`.

Answer (score 1):

```
filename=filename+name
```

Use the above code

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
I thought you have some mistaken in variable name.

```
aFile = input("Please enter the name for your txt. file: ")

fileName = (aFile + ".txt")
WRITE = "w"
APPEND = "a"

file = []
name = " "
while name != "DONE" :
    name = input("Please enter the guest name (Enter DONE if there is no   more names) : ").upper()
   file.append(name)
file.remove("DONE")
print("The guests list in alphabetical order, and it will save in " + fileName + " :")
file.sort()
for U in file :
    print(U)
outputfile = open(fileName, mode = WRITE)
outputfile.write(name)
outputfile.close()
print("file written successfully.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just right out the bat, you can not append to a toople.

```
fileName.append(name) #how can you append or remove anything into or from this when it contains toople?
```

Another thing, I don't know what version of python you are using but, I never seen expression like this

```
file = open(fileName, mode = WRITE) #this should be something like (file=open(fileName,"w"))
```

Just overall check your code. Like I said you can not add or remove stuff from a toople; only in lists and dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

`append` is the [list's method](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) where as fileName declared in your code is treated as string. If your intention is to append the string to file, open the file in "append" mode and write to it:

```
with open(aFile + ".txt", "a") as f:
    f.write("appended text")
```